# Retrieve Mail from .mbox files (Outlook Express)

Tags: email, data-recovery, outlook-express

Have a client with a borked Windows install who wants to get some mail out of his Outlook Express mail which I believe uses .mbox.

I'm looking for a decent program to do such a task.

Answer (score 1):

it's unlikely that it is mbox. outlook express stopped using mbox-like (mbx) storage in the late 90s. assuming you can boot and install applications, [thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Import_from_Outlook_Express) will import from outlook express.

if it is dbx, then you can use [dbxconv](http://www.ukrebs-software.de/english/dbxconv/dbxconv.html) to convert from dbx to mbox. from there you can import the mbox into your favorite email client.

Comment: Hi Yanokwa, I wasn't aware as I'm posting on behalf of another tech. Also using Outlook Express not Outlook just in case you're confused. What we have done is transfer the Outlook Express folder from the borked Windows install using a seperate machine and have it on a working PC, ready to attempt to get the messages out of - The folders like Inbox, sent etc are stored as various files of varying sizes, just need a program to be able to read these files and get messages out of. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to confirm, the files are .dbx format.